# Is there a limit to bluetooth dongles (for Beacon Advertising)

Tags: bluetooth

Hey happy helpful people,

this might be a generic PC or maybe UNIX question, I'm not sure. I'll ask here since I plan to do this with a Pi, but further information would be also fine.

I'm planning to create an outdoor game which relies heavily on Bluetooth Beacons (many different beacons). I can setup a dongle, I can send beacons.

**Question:** Can I setup multiple dongles? I've seen a USB Hub with 10 Ports and would like to fill all of them (maybe do this even twice). But I can't find any information if there is a limit of parallel running/advertising hci devices (from spec). Of course I can run into computing limits and maybe have to use a more powerful SBC, that would be OK.

Thank you very much!
Patrick

Comment: are you saying that you would have up to 20 beacons all in one location?

Comment: @jsotola exactly